# Using jquery functions in MVC3- '$' is undefined

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, syntax

I apologize for my lack of jquery knowledge. I'm using jquery 1.6.2, and trying to attach a jquery function to an ActionLink. Here is my jquery function:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $("addOperation").click(function () {
       $.ajax({
          url: this.href,
          cache: false,
          success: function (html) { $("#editor_rows").append(html); }
       });
       return false;
    });
    </script>
```

When I navigate to the page containing the script, the debugger comes back with the following:

```
    Microsoft JScript runtime error: '$' is undefined
```

This is pointing at the first occurence of '$'. To me, this sounds like it's not recognizing that this is a jquery call, but I haven't had trouble with this in the past. Not to mention, MVC3 should bundle and render all of the jscript files before the app loads. Any suggestions for me?

Comment: Is your jQuery script included *before* your script?

Comment: Check as first thing your html code to see if the jquery reference is before this script

Comment: Is this actually using *JScript*?

Comment: @Mathletics Microsoft always refers to it as JScript in their engine.

Comment: @vcsjones yes but it's also tagged jscript, which is probably not accurate. Editing.

Comment: @Mathletics Ah, missed the tag. Nice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Make sure your jquery script tag is above your script.
2. Wrap your code in the [document.ready](http://api.jquery.com/ready/) event:

E.g. for 1

```
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="/path/to/your.script"></script>
```

E.g. for 2

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
     //Your code here
});
```

or shorter:

```
$(function() { 
       //Your code here
});
```

This will ensure all the JavaScript has loaded before your code is executed.